# vector::clear() behind the scenes & destruction

Tags: c++, oop, stl, destructor, undefined-behavior

I’ve researched about the implementation of STL vector. 
vector container is implemented as a dynamic array. The method clear() is used for destructing all the elements in the vector, which sets the size of the vector to 0, capacity though, stays as it was. So, if I understand this correctly, all the elements are being called their destructors, but the dynamically-allocated memory stays available. And in order to still free it, we can do:

```
Vec.swap( vector<T>() ); // Capacity = 0.
```

But let’s suppose we haven’t used swap and only made a clear.
The internal implementation (correct me if I’m wrong) is about equal to the following (in a very simplified way):

```
// A contained type:
struct C {
    int m;
    C() : m(123){}
};
C * arr = new C[10];  //  Suppose this is the internal array in the container
```

EDIT:
I understand that the above new operator isn't used in the real implementation and that STL uses allocator, I just used new as a test case to test the destructors (this is just an analogy).

```
// Calling clear() :
for(size_t i=0;i<SZ;i++)
    arr[i].~C();  //  Destroying ALL elements  
// some other actions . . .
```

But now the capacity is still 10 and the memory still has some data we can access:

```
// Accessing the vector at 0:
cout<<arr[0].m<<endl;  //  This prints 123
```

Is this an undefined behavior? Well, it seems so, but I would like to know for sure.

Maybe if I understood more deeply what happens when calling a destructor (regarding to stack memory), I could know for sure, is this equal to the call of a destructor when a program goes out of the scope of a function, or calling a destructor before exiting the scope is considered to be just like any method, and the stack memory of the object isn’t freed?

Disclaimer: The code above is very simplified to symbolize part of what clear() does, and what I concluded from my research, you may correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: Is this about some hypothetical implementation of `vector` or about the mechanics of object destruction?

Comment: @honk - Both actually, since clear invokes destruction, they are both related

Comment: If I may give you a little advice then read Scott Meyer's books: Effective STL and More effective C++. In the former was explanation of your doubts, afair.

Answer (score 4):

It is correct that `std::vector<...>::clear()` just destroys the objects and sets its internal records appropriately to indicate that there are no objects. When accessing the destroyed objects you have undefined behavior: Although the bits in the data may not have changed, associated objects may have been destroyed as well and their memory reclaimed for other purposes.

In your example where `C` just stores an `int` and doesn't do anything with it in the destructor, the bits are probably unchanged but there is no guaranteed that way. In particular a debugging implementation may waste a few cycles to deliberately write garbage into the memory of the destroyed objects.

Just a side note: `std::vector<...>` won't use `new C[n]` but rather allocate and deallocate raw memory via an allocator. However, that's a details.

Comment: Does invoking destructor in scope act the same as destruction when exiting? Is the stack memory of the object freed?

Comment: @StackHeapCollision: Explicit destruction calls the destructor as does automatic destruction. If you explicitly destroy an object which is allocated on the stack you may already have undefined behavior. At the very least you need to construct an object in the same memory location because when execution leave the function all stack allocated objects are destroyed automatically. The stack memory will be used for the stack: It won't be "freed" using any of the normaly memory allocation routines, though - after all, it also wasn't "allocated". The system will manage the stack memory somehow.

Comment: Thanks. By "freed" I ment excluded from the stack, as any local variables are inserted/removed from the stack. Ofcourse I didn't mean "free" as in the dynamic-allocation terms.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your main question is:

> Is this an undefined behavior?

With a regular array, yes, you have an undefined behavior, for the reasons explained in a previous answer. But if you try to access an element of `std::vector` with an index that is equal to or greater than the *size* (beware, not beyond the *capacity*) of the vector, then the access operator will throw an `std::out_of_range` exception (although function `clear()` does invoke the destructor of each element of the vector and does *not* change its capacity, it does changes the internal count of how many elements the vector contains).

Comment: Whether an exception is guaranteed to be thrown depends on how the elements in the `std::vector<...>` are accessed: When using `v.at(i)` with an out of range index `i` an exception is thrown. When using `v[i]` as in the question the result is undefined behavior. It may throw an exception but it may also cause nasal daemons.

Comment: You are right, as the note at the end of this page proves: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/
However, I could not find the point where this is mentioned in the standard. Do you happen to know it? Thank you anyway

Comment: According to Table 101 in 23.2.3 [sequence.reqmts] `c[i]` is equivalent to `*(c.begin() + i)`. According to table 106 in 24.2.2 [iterator.iterators] it is a requirement for an iterator to be derferenceable for `*it` to be valid. According to Table 100 in 23.2.3 [sequence.reqmts] `clear()` invalidates all iterators pointing to elements of the container. I don't think there is any one location stating that the behavior is undefined but taking these clauses together states that it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Right. Actually Table 101 defines the same semantics for at(), but then clause 17 below Table 101 mentions explicitly that at() throws an out_of_range exception, while it says nothing about []. Thank you very much for this

Answer (score 0):

Your program use to memory areas: stack and heap. You put arr vector address on heap memory, but the values of m reside on stack. 
If you want to delete heap memory use delete [] arr, and if to unaddressed memory use

> arr=NULL
>   Your struct can be easily modify like that

```
struct C {
int *m;
C(int value) {
    m=new int(value);
}
~C()
{
    delete m;
}
```

};